# Time limit exceeded python while uploading on stepik

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is: introduced 2 numbers N(0-10000) - number of components, Q - number of requests. Then inputs N numbers of tests results. And then input Q numbers. Need to summarize an amount of all numbers in N which are less then Q

```
Sample Input:
10 3
2 6 8 4 5 1 9 0 3 7
3
8
0
Sample Output:
6
36
0
```

Made this task. If i m doing it local, with other random numbers it works. When i m trying to upload it on the stepik task I`ve got timelimit exceeded.

```
N, Q = input().split()
N = int(N)
Q = int(Q)
problems = input().split()
numMis = [0]*Q
MB = [0]*Q
if N > 0 or Q > 0:
    for i in range(Q):
        numMis[i] = int(input())
    for i in range(Q):
        for j in range(N):
            if numMis[i] >= int(problems[j]):
                MB[i] += int(problems[j])
    for i in range(Q):
        print(MB[i])
else:
    print('0')
```